# Change the font size in a table or settings of the table

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

Here is my current table, as you can see it has some issue with the font and the overall length and of the width of the table.
Here is the table:

[image]

and here is current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y},title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can above, there are some issues with this table. I am glad for any kind of suggestion to solve it.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see mainly tow suggestions

1. Allow the `tcolorbox` to trample on the margins by enlarging it's width.
2. Reduce the font size

%

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,
tabularx={X|*{14}{|c}},
title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt,
,grow to left by=0.5cm,
grow to right by=0.5cm]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min~\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max~\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
  \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,
tabularx={X|*{14}{|c}},
title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt,
fontupper=\small\sffamily, 
% or fontupper=\footnotesize \sffamily,
]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min~\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max~\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second table in your MWE creates an overfull box warning due to the first column being a bit too narrow. The `%` signs overlap with the vertical line. You can overcome this by slightly decreasing the tabcolsep (for example: `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}`). With this, there is also no need for a smaller font size.

Comment: Ok thank you, it worked but I had to change the font size in the document class to 11pt and I had to include the \usepackage{geometry}.

Comment: @leandriis I think  you should post and an answer as for me your suggestion is more efficient to solve the problem since there is no need any more to trample on the margins.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda: Done. I have also added a version that does not require the use of the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon [Hafid Boukhoulda's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501465/134144), I have slightly decreased the `tabcolsep`. With this, the table can fit into the textwidth without the need to decrease the font size and without overfull boxes. Please note that I have also used the `geometry` package to get a wider textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}


\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.25pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,
tabularx={X|*{14}{|c}},
title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt,
%fontupper=\small\sffamily, 
]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min~\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max~\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the `geometry` package you might be interested in one of the following two suggestions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}


\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.99pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,
tabularx={X|*{14}{|c}},
title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt,
fontupper=\small\sffamily, 
]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min~\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max~\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.65pt}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,
tabularx={X|*{14}{|c}},
title=Bestandteile von T/P92,boxrule=0.5pt,
fontupper=\footnotesize\sffamily, 
]
 & C & Mn & P & S & Si & Cr & W & Mo & V & Cb(Nb) & N & B & Al & Ni      \\\hline\hline
min~\%   & 0.07& 0.3 &  Ns &  Ns & Ns& 8.5& 1.5 & 0.3 &  0.15 & 0.04& 0.03 &  0.001 &  Ns & Ns \\
max~\% & 0.13& 0.02 &  0.01 &  0.5 & 9.5& 2& 0.6 &  0.6 &  0.25 & 0.09& 0.07 &  0.006 &  0.04 & 0.4\\\hline\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your  second solution as well and it worked, furthermore it still looked decent even with a document font size of 12pt

Answer (score 2):

I propose using `tabular*` together with `siunitx`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl} % better passing table to xcolor
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  tab2/.style={
    enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    colframe=red!50!black,
    colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
    coltitle=black,
    center title
  },
  tabular*/.style={%
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,
    before upper*={\arrayrulecolor{tcbcolframe}\def\arraystretch{1.1}%
      \expandafter\tcb@hack@currenvir\csname tabular*\endcsname{\linewidth}{#1}},
    after upper*=\csname endtabular*\endcsname\arrayrulecolor{black}},
}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  tab2,
  tabular*={
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{2pt}}
    l *{3}{T{1.2}} *{5}{T{1.1}} *{3}{T{1.2}} T{1.3} T{1.2} T{1.1}
    @{\hspace{2pt}}
  },
  title=Bestandteile von T/P92,
  boxrule=0.5pt
]
 & {C} & {Mn} & {P} & {S} & {Si} & {Cr} & {W} & {Mo} & {V} & {Cb(Nb)} & {N} & {B} & {Al} & {Ni}
\\
\midrule
min\% & 0.07& 0.3  & {Ns} & {Ns} & {Ns} & 8.5 & 1.5 & 0.3 & 0.15 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.001 & {Ns} & {Ns}
\\
max\% & 0.13& 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.5  & 9.5  & 2   & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.25 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.006 & 0.04 & 0.4
\\
\end{tcolorbox}

\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `tabular*` style is not available with the standard `tcolorbox`, but it would be an interesting addition.

[image]

After looking at the typeset table, it will be immediately apparent whether reducing the font size with `\small` or `\footnotesize` is necessary.

Comment: See https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/75 for the feature request.

Comment: Version 4.21 of `tcolorbox` will have a `tabulars` option to the effect shown in the answer, so it will be sufficient to remove the style definition and to replace `tabular*` with `tabulars`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with TikZ. Notice that in `node`, we have option `scale`, `xscale`, `yscale` that is more flexible than LaTeX's font options `Large`, `\small`, `\tiny`, etc.

[image]

```
%\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.2,yscale=.5,font=\sffamily]

\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\draw[brown] (0,1) rectangle +(8,-4);
\draw[brown,fill=pink] (0,0) rectangle +(8,1);
\foreach \i in {2,...,8}
\draw[brown] (\i,0)--+(-90:3);
\draw[brown] (0,0) rectangle +(8,-3);
\draw[double,brown] 
(1,0)--+(-90:3) (0,-1)--+(0:8) (0,-3)--+(0:8);
\end{scope}

\path[right=-5mm]
(0,-1) node{min \%}
(0,-2) node{max \%};

\path
(1,0) node{C} (1,-1)  node{0.07} (1,-2) node{0.13}
(2,0) node{Mn} (2,-1) node{0.3} (2,-2)  node{0.02}
(3,0) node{P} (3,-1)  node{Ns} (3,-2)   node{0.01}
(4,0) node{S} (4,-1)  node{Ns} (4,-2)   node{0.5}
(5,0) node{Si} (5,-1) node{Ns} (5,-2)   node{9.5}
(6,0) node{Cr} (6,-1) node{8.5} (6,-2)  node{2}
(7,0) node{W} (7,-1)  node{1.5} (7,-2)  node{0.6};

\path (3.5,1) node[xscale=1.2,yscale=.8,font=\bfseries]
{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont Bestandteile von T/P92};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `xscale` and `yscale` being set to a different value, the text looks unfortunately quite distorted.

Comment: @leandriis: inside a node `xscale` `yscale` does transform text's shape, outside it does not